# The lengths of the sides of a triangle are given as $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 5|c|^2$ , where $|k|$ denotes the absolute value of $k$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, problem-solving

> The lengths of the sides of a triangle are given as $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 5|c|^2$ , where $|k|$ denotes the absolute value of $k$. Prove that the medians drawn from $A$ and $B$ are perpendicular.

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture :-

[image]

I would normally solve these kind of problems using elementary geometry, but I wasn't able to do it this time, simply because $(a,b,c)$ can take many values and there is probably some kind of construction or some clever proof which I am missing. One idea I thought of is that the medians divide the side lengths into $2$ equal parts, and the centroid itself divides the medians in $2:1$ ratio, and I probably have to show somehow, that Pythagoras Theorem on either of the $3$ triangles work. I took an example in Geogebra by drawing an accurate diagram with $a = 12$ , $b = 18.66$ nearly, and then $c = 10$ . This actually showed that the medians from $A$ and $B$ are really perpendicular, and I just drew a picture of that taken from Geogebra.

Now given $(a,b,c)$ , is there any way to prove this? I did not find any elementary methods like angle-chasing , pythagoras theorem , similarity and areas , etc. , but I did not find any clever use of them till now. Maybe some extra construction is required?

Can anyone help me? Thank You.

Comment: Absolute values are unnecessary, both because this is a geometry problem and because the variables are squared.

Comment: My bad, let me fix it, is it ok now?

Comment: Is that what the problem originally said? Using the greatest integer function completely changes the problem.

Comment: Yes it did, if it were the case of absolute values then the problem would actually be disproved by an example.

Comment: $a = 2, b = c = \frac{3}{2}$ is a counterexample for the problem with the greatest integer function. What was your counterexample?

Comment: Does $a = 2$ and $b = c = \frac{3}{2}$ satisfy the equation $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 5|c|^2$?

Comment: If you are using the greatest integer function, yes.

Comment: It was true for absolute value and it is false now for the greatest integer function.

Comment: @MishaLavrov changed it again, actually you are right as that worked when the exact values in the picture were there, which would not be true for the greatest integer function. Also absolute value will be unnecessary here as Joshua pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let DB and EA meet at X. From the [triangle median theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius%27s_theorem)
$$DB^2= \frac12( AB^2+ BC^2)-\frac14 AC^2, \>\>\>
EA^2= \frac12( AB^2+ AC^2)-\frac14 BC^2
$$
Combine them, along with the given $BC^2+AC^2=5AB^2$, to get
$$DB^2 +EA^2 = AB^2 +\frac14(BC^2+AC^2)= \frac94 AB^2$$

and substitute it into the cosine rule below
\begin{align}
\cos\angle DXE= \frac{DX^2+EX^2- DE^2}{2 DX\cdot EX}= \frac{\frac19 (DB^2+EA^2)- \frac14 AB^2}{2DX\cdot EX}=0
\end{align}Thus, $\angle DXE =90^\circ$ and the two medians are perpendicular.

Answer (score 2):

Given four points $W,X,Y,Z$, let $P_{WXYZ} = WX^2 - XY^2 + YZ^2 - ZW^2$. Then we can prove that:

**Claim 1.** $P_{WXYZ}$ is affine-linear in each of the four points. (That is, as one of the points, say, $X$, moves along a straight line at a constant rate, the value of $P_{WXYZ}$ changes linearly.)

**Claim 2.** When $W,X,Y,Z$ are all distinct, $P_{WXYZ}=0$ if and only if $WY \perp XZ$.

---

So let's compute $P_{ADEB}$. By Claim 1 applied to point $D$ (which is halfway between $A$ and $C$), $P_{ADEB} = \frac12 P_{AAEB} + \frac12 P_{ACEB}$. By Claim 1 applied to point $E$ (which is halfway between $B$ and $C$), we get
$$
    P_{ADEB} = \frac14 P_{AABB} + \frac14 P_{AACB} + \frac14 P_{ACBB} + \frac14 P_{ACCB}.
$$
Since we only want to know if $P_{ADEB}=0$, we can forget about the $\frac14$'s and only expand out these four expressions in terms of $AB^2, BC^2, CA^2$.

We get
$$
   (AA^2-AB^2+BB^2-BA^2) + (AA^2-AC^2+CB^2-BA^2) + (AC^2-CB^2+BB^2-BA^2) + (AC^2-CC^2+CB^2-BA^2)
$$
which simplifies to $AC^2 + BC^2 - 5AB^2$. We are given that this is $0$, therefore $P_{ADEB}=0$ and $AE \perp BD$ by Claim 2.

Answer (score 1):

Note $P$ the intersection point and consider the triangle $\triangle{ABP}$ so we have by the well known formulas for the medians
$$AP=\frac23\left(\frac{\sqrt{2(b^2+c^2)-a^2}}{2}\right)\\PB=\frac23\left(\frac{\sqrt{2(a^2+c^2)-b^2}}{2}\right)\\AB=c$$
It is verified directly and easily that $AP^2+PB^2=AB^2$ because of $a^2+b^2=5c^2$